# Receiving an error "Main.c:9:22: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier" in C programming

Tags: c, iteration

I'm new to C Language and was trying to print the Fibonacci series but I constantly receive the error that is shown in the title. Anybody can help a newbie?

I've tried adding a semi colon after the "i++" and all I get is huge series of negative numbers that automatically terminate the program. I've tried compiling it using 2 different websites that offer c language execution and compilation.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,i,sum;
    i = 1;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    for (i <= 10; i++)
    {
        sum = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = sum;
        printf("%d", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 but I got no output at all

Comment: `for (;i <= 10; i++)` if you omit the `i = 1` (a `for` loop declaration always has 2 `';'`)

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this

```
for (i <= 10; i++)
```

To this:

```
for (; i <= 10; i++)
```

You have to do this because according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for), the syntax is

> for ( init_clause ; cond_expression ; iteration_expression )
>   loop_statement

In your case there's no `init_clause` (it's optional), but you still need the `;` after it.

You could also remove the `i = 1;` earlier in your code and instead put it into your loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

since you don't need `i` outside of the loop anyway.